# How to convert byte array or base64 image to static QR code

Tags: php, android, .net, base64, qr-code

I am trying to convert an image to a static QR code!
What do I want to do?
Converting an image to QR code, like convert image to base64 then convert the image from text to Qr code, but the base64 text is too long text and not acceptable to conversions

So, How I Can put the image inside the QR code and read it from my app

Comment: One cannot put images as qr code. Only text.  And what is a static qr code? Pretty unclear what you have and have in mind.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean: _"[How Do I Add An Image To A QR Code?](http://qrcode.meetheed.com/question35.php)"_? Yet, the word "convert" seems to suggest not.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We can convert image to BASE64 text, but the issue with this way is that the BASE64 test is so long

Answer (score 0):

[QR code can carry about 3KB of payload](https://www.qrcode-tiger.com/qr-code-data-size) - enough for text/url. So ensure that your base64 version of image is less than this limit. Btw. I doubt that you can fit into a readable image, maybe some 50x50px...

Comment: It is a bill images , so it can't be 50X50

Comment: so QR code can't carry such data